# Embed result of sizeof() offsetof() macros into a const char array?

Tags: string, macros, embed, constants, sizeof

Can a C pre-processsor macro be used to generate the string below where size is the result of the sizeof macro?

```
const char testXmlElement [] = "< xs:element name="count" size="4" \>";
```

Use of the stringizing macro generates the result size="sizeof(int)" instead of the desired result, size="4".

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
const char testXmlElement[] =
"<element size=\"" 
xstr(sizeof(int))
"\""
" \\>";
```

My intention was to create an XML schema in an embedded microcontroller application using both the sizeof() and offsetof() macros.  The resulting schema would be used to de-serialize XML to nested C data structures.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so.  The preprocessor runs before the compiler, and `sizeof` is interpreted by the compiler.

Comment: Right, `sizeof` is an operator, not a macro.  `offsetof` is a macro, but it expands to an integer constant expression, one that the preprocessor probably won't be able to evaluate.  Stringizing the result of `offsetof()` will give you a moderately complex expression, not an integer literal.

Comment: Thank you both for helping me understand and pointing out sizeof is an operator.