# GNU C preprocessor: Stringify the result of a macro evaluation

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, stringification

I have a common string macro that I want to convert to a length-value string, all within macros, if possible, so everything ends up in `.rodata`.

```
#define PAYLOAD "xyz"
#define PAYLOAD_LEN (sizeof(PAYLOAD)-1)
```

I would like to use PAYLOAD_LEN, as a string, in part of another string, e.g.

```
const char lv_macro[]  = "<preamble>" PAYLOAD_LEN ":" PAYLOAD;
const char lv_wanted[] = "<preamble>3:xyz"`
```

I suspect that this is not possible, and that I should just define PAYLOAD_LEN as a literal, e.g. `#define PAYLOAD_LEN 3` and then [stringify](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html).

I could, but do not want to, forget about `.rodata` and generate it at run-time, e.g.

```
char lv[64];
snprintf(lv, sizeof lv, "<preamble>%zu:" PAYLOAD, PAYLOAD_LEN);
```

*Please note that this is not the question that has been asked and answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419332/c-preprocessor-stringify-the-result-of-a-macro), for example, and in many other questions.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed result of sizeof() offsetof() macros into a const char array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661662/embed-result-of-sizeof-offsetof-macros-into-a-const-char-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` is handled by the compiler, not the preprocessor, so you can't take that approach. The other two options will work, and which one is better suited depends on your circumstances.