# How to check the size of a structure at compile time?

Tags: c++, data-structures, static-assert

I want to add code that during compilation checks the size of a structure to make sure that it is a predefined size. For example I want to make sure that the size of this structure is 1024 byte when I am porting this code or when I am adding/removing items from structure during compile time:

```
#pack(1)
struct mystruct
{
    int item1;
    int item2[100];
    char item3[4];
    char item5;
    char padding[615];
 }
```

I know how to do this during run time by using a code such as this:

```
 if(sizeof(mystruct) != 1024)
 { 
     throw exception("Size is not correct");
 }
```

But it is a waste of processing if I do this during run time. I need to do this during compile time.

How can I do this during compilation?

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't know anything about C++, it only has a very limited set of tokens that it can operate on. You might get somewhere with a static_assert.

Comment: The `sizeof` part is still done at compile time. For a compile time assertion, `static_assert` would work fine.

Comment: you can find an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526526/how-to-combine-static-assert-with-sizeof-and-stringify)

Comment: This is the kind of thing that should be checked in a Unit Test, not in the program itself.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since C++11, you can check the size during compilation:

```
static_assert (sizeof(mystruct) == 1024, "Size is not correct");
```

Pre-c++11 compilers, Boost has a workaround:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(sizeof(mystruct) == 1024, "Size is not correct");
```

See [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html).

Comment: Note: regarding the workaround, a non-Boost solution is simply `char const Array[sizeof(mystruct) == 1024 ? 1 : -1];`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. with boost you will probably get a nicer error message (at least something with "static assertion failure" in it, if not your own message).

Comment: agreed, but some people have to do without.

Comment: If the compiler supports C++11, Boost uses `static_assert`; if not, it falls back to the template instantiation technique, or possibly uses some compiler-specific trick to improve the error message (it recognizes many compilers and adapts itself for them).

Answer (score 27):

If you don't have C++11 or Boost, you could try this:

```
typedef char assertion_on_mystruct[(   sizeof(mystruct)==1024   )*2-1 ];
```

If the statement is false, then this typedefs an array type with negative size, and your compiler should give an error message.  If true, then the size will be one, a valid size.  For example, g++ gives:

```
template.cpp:10:70: error: size of array ‘assertion_on_mystruct’ is negative
```

I admit it's not the most useful thing, because it only tells you the line number of the error.  But it is the simplest, stand-alone, technique I can think of.

A more general macro is:

```
#define DUMB_STATIC_ASSERT(test) typedef char assertion_on_mystruct[( !!(test) )*2-1 ]

DUMB_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(mystruct)==1024 );
DUMB_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(my_other_struct)==23 );
DUMB_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(minimum_size_struct) >= 23 );
```

Comment: This will work even if you don't have ++ at all, in plain old C. In C++ the template specialization approach is usually preferred though.

Comment: I came across this suggestion while looking for an answer to the same problem.  I like that this can go in a header where the <linux/kernel.h> BUILD_BUG_ON stuff all needs to go in a function.  However, I don't like that it creates unnecessary compiler symbols.  Any idea if there's a way around that???   I'm in "plain old C", and updating to C11 is a non-option.

Comment: Ok, I came up with this: `#define SIZE_CHECK_STRUCT( sname, maxsize ) typedef  char sname ## _size_check_struct [ 1 - 2* !!(sizeof(struct sname) > (maxsize)) ]`.  Leave out `struct` keyword for a version that works on typedef'ed structures.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland, thanks for the `!!` trick, to force an expression into a boolean. I've edited mine accordingly

Comment: @BrianMcFarland, after seeing your use of `##`, I became worried that mine would fail if there were multiple succesful asserts, because it would mean multiple definitions of the typedef `assertion_on_mystruct`. But it seems it is not a problem (g++ 4.8.4). I think it works because all the definitions are identical (they're all based on `true`, by definition of being successful). Does the standard allow multiple definitions of a typedef, as long as all are identical types? If so, then I think my current version is reasonably robust.

Comment: I'm in C, not C++, but I just tested this and apparently `gcc` won't even issue a warning for multiple identical typedefs unless you specify "-Wpedantic".  It's only an error if the types are conflicting.

Comment: Perhaps we could arrange that the line number `__LINE__` is included in the name of the typedef? Or maybe just wrap it inside a `do{ }while(0)`?

Answer (score 7):

From C++11 you have [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) which is handled on compilation:

```
static_assert(sizeof(mystruct) == 1024, "Size is not correct");
```

If the size is not `1024` bytes, you will get a compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check it at *compile time* you may use template metaprogramming phase.

In standard C++ you have boost's [static assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html), which is hidden by a macro `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`.
You would use it in the following way:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
...
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(mystruct) == 1024);
```

The above code will fail to compile if the assertion is not met, with some semi-readable error message.

In C++11 you get simpler functionality with [static assertions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Static_assertions) which introduces a new keyword `static_assert`.

```
static_assert(sizeof(mystruct) == 1024,"Size is not correct");
```

---

Doing the same thing at *preprocessor* phase cannot be done but it seems not to be really needed in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that padding is included in sizeof():

```
struct A { int i; bool b; };

typedef char assertion_on_A[( ((sizeof(A)))== 8 )*2-1 ];
static_assert(sizeof(A) == 8, "sizeof A");
```

Both the typedef and the static_assert expect size 8 here.

Comment: Note that OP uses `#pack(1)`, which means padding is not used, I'm pretty sure...

Comment: @Alexis: tested it with -O3, no error;

Comment: I see. I guess I misread the question. The `#pack(1)` is not an issue. Testing the resulting size is.